# How to link a custom post type to a user role in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

Hello I have been building a project using wordpress. And now I am stuck somewhere. I want to enable each company registered in my website to be able to see in their profile page user submitted complains about them. I was thinking maybe a custom taxonamy would be used here or a custom post type which would then be linked to the company profile. Please anybody that can help with this should help me out even if it is a wordpress plugin that can solve my problem please I would appretiate.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this plugin-

[Discussion board](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-discussion-board/)

It fits best on your requirement.